# I have a domain name, How do I point it to my local Windows server running IIS?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7

I have a domain name from GoDaddy, How do I point it to my local Windows server so that the application running on 10.0.3.89:8900 can be seen by the whole internet ?

How do I juggle bindings, Do I have to use Nameservers  like other online we hosts ( e.g ns1.godaddy.com , ns2.godaddy.com ? ).

Thank  you.

Answer (score 1):

> **Don't host on your own hardware (unless you really know what you're doing)**
>   This is a really a Very Bad Idea. Your server will be slow, your
>   website will be unreliable, and the entire
>   network will probably get hacked. Not good.
>
> You've been hacked
>
> You could also buy your own server hardware dedicated to hosting the
>   website. In order to do this, however, you'll need a solid
>   understanding of network hardware and software, a blazing-fast
>   internet connection, and a reliable power supply. Even then, you still
>   might be opening up your network to security risks, the upfront
>   costs could be significant, and the site will still likely never be as
>   fast as it would be if hosted in an enterprise data center.

However, if you'd like to do that you'll need to use a static IP service (Fixed IP).

You'll need to forward port 80 on your router to the web server. This usually isn't recommended for small/basic networks, so make sure you know what you're doing.

For more info, you can refer to below links:

[How to Host Your Own Website](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/how-to-host-your-own-website/)
[Can I host my own website with my own computer? How would I go about doing that?](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-host-my-own-website-with-my-own-computer-How-would-I-go-about-doing-that)
[What equipment would I need to launch my own web hosting server](https://www.quora.com/What-equipment-would-I-need-to-launch-my-own-web-hosting-server)

In my opinion, It's better that you should host on [VPS](http://www.google.com/search?q=vps). It can have any operating system you'd like. And you control it. It is much cheaper that dedicated hosting on your hardware.

here are a few services you might want to consider for VPS

https://aws.amazon.com/
https://www.digitalocean.com/
https://www.heroku.com/ (this one have free hosting if you don't mind the 24/7 uptime)